# C recursion practice won't display output

Tags: c

This is my attempt at recursion. It compiles and runs, but doesn't display the factorial of the number that I input. I'm attempting this with Geany on Ubuntu.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int fact(int n);
int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Give me a number");
    scanf("%6d", &n);
    fact(n);
}   

int fact(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * fact(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect this to output anything?

Comment: A return value is not magically printed. You need `printf("%d\n", fact(n));`

Comment: Where do you actually output anything in your code?

Comment: regarding: ` scanf("%6d", &n);`  do not put a size limit on values that are inputting numbers

Comment: since the code is working with `int` values the values will overflow (approx) when 'n' reaches/exceeds 12  resulting in undefined behavior.  Suggest using `uint64_t`

Answer (score 1):

> doesn't display the factorial of the number that I input.

in

> ```
> int main()
> {
>     int n;
>     printf("Give me a number");
>     scanf("%6d", &n);
>     fact(n);
> }
> ```

you do not print the result of factorial, then it is not print

why are you using "%6d" rather than "%d" in the *scanf* ? you do not print so you do not need that

I also encourage you

- to add a separator after *Give me a number* else the input number will seem attached to it (I used a ':' below)
- to test the result of *scanf*

So, for instance :

```
int main()
{
    int n;

    printf("Give me a number:");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1)
      printf("fact(%d)=%d\n", n, fact(n));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the print statement.
You could save the result in a variable and then print it.

printf("%d",fact(n));

Comment: When I started coding in C, my hello world code did not compile, And I did not know why, it took me two days to find out that I had to save it before compiling, things that are done automatically for you today by any modern IDE. Stick to it and every thing will be OK. Got an A+ afterward

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, but you forget to to print the return value of function *fact()* change this portion of your code

```
    scanf("%6d", &n);
    fact(n);
```

to this:

```
    scanf("%6d", &n);
    printf("%d", fact(n));
```

Your work will done. after replacing your main() function will look like:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Give me a number");
    scanf("%6d", &n);
    printf("%d", fact(n));
}
```

**Note:** The factorial of 17 or higher is not adjust in integer limit.